# How to get PDF report with JavaMelody

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-melody

I´m currently monitoring a JavaEE Web-Application with JavaMelody.
In the Browser I can view all the statistics, but I want to have a pdf report.

I use Maven and already added the needed dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
            <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
            <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
            <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

How do I get the report as a PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have added the iText dependency in your webapp, JavaMelody will autodetect iText and will add a "PDF" link at the top of the reports.

Click on that "PDF" link and you will have the report you want as PDF.